# Convert google sheet to html and send as email using google app scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am currently trying to email a google sheet on a daily basis using google app scripts, I would like to convert a specific tab/worksheet on my sheets document to html and populate the email body. So far i have come up with the code below, but unfortunately it sends the email in pdf format which does not suffice as a solution for my problem. I appreciate all the help i can get.

```
function sendEmailWithAttachments() {
  var fileId = 'Sheet id';
  // Send an email with an attachment: a file from Google Drive (as a PDF)
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
  MailApp.sendEmail('Email', 'file name',
    'One File IS Attached.', {
      name: 'Subject',
      attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), ]
    });
  MailApp.sendEmail('email2', 'file name',
    'One File IS Attached.', {
      name: 'subject',
      attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), ]
    });
}
```

Comment: You will have to get the values (and possibly formatting) using SpreadsheetApp and create the HTML content yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `file.getAs()` function is retrieving the file and the *MimeType.PDF* passed is telling the function to get it as a pdf.  The `attachments: []` is then setting this pdf as an attachment to the email and not the body.

What I am reading your desire as is to create an email body as an HML with the data presented.
See this [tutorial on a Simple Mail Merge](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) which will allow you to format the data as you see fit via a template.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, the mail merge does not help solve the problem as i need to grab the data from the spreadsheet, convert it to html and then email it to multiple people.

Comment: You would need to format the HTML data in your script or in a second tab in the sheet in a cell or using formulas.  So if you wanted to show the data in a table, you would create the table as a string in the code or in a separate tab, with replacement point "place holders" for the data.  Then use the merge code to replace the place holders.